# より usage related question

Tags: grammar, particle-より

> 「もちろんです。孤高な完璧さ**より**不完全な美。お姉さまは、かのミロのヴィーナスのような存在なのです」

I came across this sentence and at first I have understand "不完全な美 is better than 孤高な完璧さ", but with the context it have to be "孤高な完璧さ is better than 不完全な美 ". Have I made a mistake in interpreting this sentence? より has a pattern with the first object (In this case, 孤高な完璧さ) is more than the second object (不完全な美)?

Comment: "**Rather than** lofty perfection, (you epitomize/exemplify/embody) imperfect beauty"

Comment: Your initial understanding is correct. What is often seen in this type of question is that the questioner misunderstands "the context" rather than the actual sentence being asked. Venus de Milo can be understood as an example of 不完全な美. Is there anything else that affects your interpretation of this sentence?

Comment: Nop, I understand now, thanks y'all.